# Heroku search for index.html in wrong folder, how solve it?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I have a React app project using Node Express. I'm trying to deploy it on heroku. I think everything is working fine except that my `server.js`is looking for `index.html` file in the wrong folder.

How to solve it?

My folder structure looks like this:

[image: My Folder structure]

I have logged in to bash in heroku. I have everything there. When I go into `dist` folder in frontend I can see the dist folder. But when running the server.js it trying to find `index.html` in the server folder. But it's in frontend. How to solve it?

This is my code in `server.js` file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static("frontend/dist"));

  app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "frontend", "dist", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

Comment: where is your "server.js" file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

Note: if server.js file is in the server folder.

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../frontend", "dist", "index.html"));
```

for more detail : [path.resolve([...paths])](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)